# Testing File Creation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tdd

My App saves Files to the Filesystem via an base64 encoded API. Here is my (simplified) controller:

```
def create
  file = "name.pdf"
  folder = "downloads"

  FileUtils::mkdir_p folder

  f = File.open File.join(folder, file), "wb"
  if f.write Base64.decode64(params[:file])
  f.close
end
```

Now I want to test for an actual file creation. How do I check whether there is a file or not?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: use [`File::exist`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-exist-3F)?

Comment: What about using a service object? This way you can test the file creation in isolation. Furthermore you can then use a stringio object for testing.